# Why does C print my hex values incorrectly?

Tags: c

So I'm a bit of a newbie to C and I am curious to figure out why I am getting this unusual behavior.

I am reading a file 16 bits at a time and just printing them out as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define endian(hex) (((hex & 0x00ff) << 8) + ((hex & 0xff00) >> 8))

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
  const int SIZE = 2;
  const int NMEMB = 1;
  FILE *ifp; //input file pointe
  FILE *ofp; // output file pointer

  int i;
  short hex;
  for (i = 2; i < argc; i++)
   {
    // Reads the header and stores the bits
    ifp = fopen(argv[i], "r");
    if (!ifp) return 1;
    while (fread(&hex, SIZE, NMEMB, ifp))
     {
      printf("\n%x", hex);
      printf("\n%x", endian(hex)); // this prints what I expect
      printf("\n%x", hex);
      hex = endian(hex);
      printf("\n%x", hex);
     }   
   }
 }
```

The results look something like this:

```
ffffdeca
cade // expected
ffffdeca
ffffcade
0
0 // expected
0
0
600
6 // expected
600
6
```

Can anyone explain to me why the *last* line in each block doesn't print the same value as the second?

Comment: the `#define endian(hex) (((hex & 0x00ff) << 8) + ((hex & 0xff00) >> 8))` can be simplified to `#define endian(hex) (hex & 0xFFFF)` lol. that is overly complex for such a simple conversion

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is due to integer type-promotion.

Your `shorts` are being implicitly promoted to `int`. (which is 32-bits here) So these are sign-extension promotions in this case.

Therefore, your `printf()` is printing out the hexadecimal digits of the full 32-bit `int`.

When your `short` value is negative, the sign-extension will fill the top 16 bits with ones, thus you get `ffffcade` rather than `cade`.

---

The reason why this line:

```
printf("\n%x", endian(hex));
```

seems to work is because your macro is implicitly getting rid of the upper 16-bits.

Answer (score 21):

The placeholder `%x` in the format string interprets the corresponding parameter as `unsigned int`.

To print the parameter as `short`, add a length modifier `h` to the placeholder:

```
printf("%hx", hex);
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders

Answer (score 2):

You have implicitly declared `hex` as a signed value (to make it unsigned write `unsigned short hex`) so that any value over `0x8FFF` is considered to be negative. When printf displays it as a 32-bit `int` value it is sign-extended with ones, causing the leading `Fs`. When you print the return value of `endian` before truncating it by assigning it to `hex` the full 32 bits are available and printed correctly.