# Why does fwrite print hexadecimal value backwards?

Tags: c, fwrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does C print my hex values incorrectly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441257/why-does-c-print-my-hex-values-incorrectly)

I'm output fwrite information to a binary file but when I look at it in xxd the output for the hex is not in order. Is this how the binary file is supposed to look?

code to print to destination:

```
  int delim[] = { 0xabcd1234 };
  fwrite(delim, 4, 1, destination);
  char buffer[] = "I like dog";
  fwrite(buffer, 1, 10, destination);
```

xxd output:

```
0000000: 3412 cdab 4920 6c69 6b65 2064 6f67       4...I like dog
```

As you can see the hexadecimal number is 3412 cdab instead of abcd1234

Answer (score 4):

Because that's how your processor apparently stores integers.

More about this on Wikipedia - [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: It is not the operating system, but the processor that enforces endianness.

Comment: @AlanHaggaiAlavi That's what it says :-)

Comment: However, before the edit, it was not the case. :-)

Answer (score 3):

As Tom van der Woredt pointed out, this is an endianness issue (and possibly an issue of xxd, make it dump single bytes, not double).

If you want to make sure the hex is in a specific order on in the file, use an array of unsigned characters, instead:

```
unsigned char delim[] = {0xab, 0xcd, 0x12, 0x34};
fwrite(delim, sizeof *delim, sizeof delim,  destination);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the little endian way of storing integers by the processor.