# Showing Bytes in C

Tags: c, byte

I am writing a C program that has to show each operation in a hexadecimal answer but you have to show all the bytes corresponding to the data type.

for example if its an int it should show 8 bytes, if its a short 4 bytes.

It works for every other data type including char where it only shows two bytes. But short is always showing 8 bytes when I print it

```
char x5 = 0xa1;
short z5 = x5;

printf("\nProblem 1f: %x\n", z5);
```

and it prints "Problem 1f: ffffffa1"

a classmate found a solution where %hx prints the correct amount of bytes but I dont understand why this %x prints extra bytes, where are these bytes coming from?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does C print my hex values incorrectly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441257/why-does-c-print-my-hex-values-incorrectly)

Comment: This happens because of integer promotion. You `char` is a 8-bit signed value, `0xa1` is `b1010 0001`, the most significant bit is set to 1, so when it gets promoted to integer (with the short assignment and later in the `printf`, sign extension is applied, that fills all other 3 bytes with ones. You end up with `b1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1010 0001` which is `ffffffa1`.

Comment: Looks correct to me. `char` is one byte, printed as two hex digits. `short` is 4 bytes, printed as 8 hex digits.

Comment: @Pablo is right.  Try this: What happens when `x5=0x7f`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printf adds extra \`FFFFFF\` to hex print from a char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090616/printf-adds-extra-ffffff-to-hex-print-from-a-char-array)

Answer (score 2):

This is due to silent integer type-promotion. Since `0xa1` is negative value (-95 dec) 
`char`, `short` will be promoted to 4 bytes `int` and printed negative by `printf` function.

To prevent promotion you can use `unsigned` types.

Program below illustrates the behaviour for signed and unsigned types:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char x5 = 0xa1;
    short z5 = x5;
    int i5 = x5;

    unsigned char ux5 = 0xa1;
    unsigned short uz5 = 0xa1;
    unsigned int ui5 = 0xa1;

    size_t sx5 = sizeof(x5);
    size_t sz5 = sizeof(z5);
    size_t si5 = sizeof(i5);


    printf("%zu %zu %zu\n", sx5, sz5, si5);  

    printf("%x %x %x\n", x5, z5, i5);     // silent promotion to 32 bit negative integers

    printf("%x %x %x\n", ux5, uz5, ui5);  // no promotion

    ux5 = x5;   
    uz5 = z5; // remember that z5 is negative number
    ui5 = i5; // same for i5

    printf("%x %x %x\n", ux5, uz5, ui5); // no promotion but numbers are negative ones

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 4
ffffffa1 ffffffa1 ffffffa1
a1 a1 a1
a1 ffa1 ffffffa1
```

Comment: Good answer, UP from me, only a minor complain: Use `%zu` when printing `size_t`.

Comment: @Pablo Thank you Pablo! I will remember about `%z` now.

Answer (score 0):

Since `x5` large enough (anything over `127` or `0x7F` in a single-byte data type) to have the highest bit set (**1**010 0001), it's interpreted as a negative when using the default signed type.  As the other answer mentioned, using an `unsigned char` fixes the issue.  However typecasting `x5` will work as well, since short uses two bytes to store the value and will not see it as negative even if it is signed (**0**000 0000 1010 0001).

typecasting will work:

```
char x5 = 0xa1;
short z5 = (unsigned char) x5;
```

and so will using an unsigned char:

```
unsigned char x5 = 0xa1;
short z5 = x5;
```

but you should really specify unsigned for everything if you're using it this way to avoid such scenarios.

```
unsigned char x5 = 0xa1;
unsigned short z5 = x5;
```